# How to enable C++ modules support in Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Tags: c++, module

I read this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-modules-in-visual-studio-2017/

And I assume that this also applies to the Visual Studio 2019 Preview.
I was setting up a project to use a new experimental implementation of modules.

But my compiler does not compile this:

```
import std.core;
```

with errors:

> 1>C:\Users\Andrey\source\repos\MyCppTests\MyCppTests\MyCppTests.cpp(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   1>C:\Users\Andrey\source\repos\MyCppTests\MyCppTests\MyCppTests.cpp(9): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'std'

I did enable /experimental:module option and /std:c++latest option.
But it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

My bad. I did enable **/experimental:module** option only for one build type but compiled in another.